# Where is Powershell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I just uninstalled Powershell 1.0 and installed Powershell 2.0. Where are the Start Menu shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer in the comments [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/10/27/windows-management-framework-is-here.aspx).

The Start Menu icons are located under Start > All Programs > Accessories now.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, since it's where CMD lives. Now, if only CMD would die :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had shorcuts in the quick launch bar-these remained.